# How can I retrieve the current user email address?

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

my question is about a Xamarin forms application.
To log my user in, I've followed the following tutorial :

https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=building-cross-platform-mobile-apps-csharp-xamarin-azure-update&author=matt-milner&name=059dcc38-df00-47ed-9e40-a943cf3b97ce&clip=4&mode=live

In order to use the user identity later in my application, I need to get my user e-mail address after connection.

The method I actually use returns me a 401 error.
Does someone know how to fix my problem ?

the login method used to connect the user (in the android app):

```
    public async Task LoginUser(MobileServiceClient m)
    {
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        var store = AccountStore.Create(context, "pass");
        var user = await m.LoginAsync(context, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, Constants.LOGIN_RETURN_URI_SCHEME);
        CacheUserCredentials(m.MobileAppUri.OriginalString, user);
    }
```

The method in my service:

```
    public async Task<string> GetUserId()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://fi-mobtest.azurewebsites.net/api/UserInfo?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0", string.Empty));
        var result = await azCli.InvokeApiAsync<HttpResponseMessage>("UserInfo", HttpMethod.Get, null);
        //var response = await hp.GetStringAsync(ur);
        //return response;
        return null;
    }
```

the method of the api api asked by the method:

```
    public string GetUserInfo()
    {
        HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
        string userName = currentContext.User.Identity.Name;
        return userName;
    }
```

Actually the API returns me the e-mail address when called from a web browser, and I have access to the UserId and an instance of MobileServiceUser from the package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.

Thank you for your help;

Comment: doesn't LoginAsync return the e-mail as the UserID?

Comment: firstly, the link is you included is only visible after you sign is. Secondly, your API call looks like it's not sending any auth token. Generally, 401 means that the token you are sending is not valid. Are you sure you don't have to send auth token? Didn't something change in API?

Comment: I know about the link @lawiluk, I just put this here to let you know more about how my program does work. AzCli contains a user of type MobileServiceUser that have a UserId and a MobileServiceAuthenticationToken. But I don't know what I can do to retrieve my user e-mail.
This call

var response = await hp.GetStringAsync(ur);

returns me a 401 error.

This one

        var result = await azCli.InvokeApiAsync<HttpResponseMessage>("UserInfo", HttpMethod.Get, null);

returns me a null value.

Comment: @Jason No, loginAsync is returning a UserId like this:"sid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to retrieve all the informations I needed

```
        hp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://MyDomain.azurewebsites.net");
        var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/.auth/me");
        msg.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", azCli.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
        msg.Headers.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
        var resp= await hp.SendAsync(msg);
        var rep = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return r.ToString();
```

This way I'm getting a json containing all the informations available about the current user.